# Quote Calculator: Finding the sum of 3 previous calculations returns NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've been working on a calculator in Jquery. It's composed of a few initial calcultions that display totals in the frontend.

1. It calculates the measurements the user inputs and multiplies this with the base product(woocommerce) price to give an initial total.
2. It allows users to select various addons such as 'cut outs' and calculates the quantity to come up with a total value for the 'add ons'.
3. It allows users to select a few extras such as 'delivery' via input checkboxes which once again calculates them to provide a total cost for the extra touches.

This leaves me with 3 total figures for the calculator so far in their own fields/divs. I've given these each a class of 'sumthree'.

I'm then wanting to add these totals up to make an overall total for the calculator.

I've tried variations such as trying to pull the data using text, value and HTML. They're not all inputs so value didn't seem correct to me. Ive also tried using parseFloat instead of parseInt but no luck so far.

It always pulls NaN, but from what I can tell I correctly declared 'finalquote' in the code at the end. I'm under the understanding this could've been the issue.

```
        <div class="form-section quote">
        <input id="works-result" value="12" readonly>
        </div>
<div class="splashback-calc">
    <h4>Splashback/s</h4>
    <div class="splashback-row">
    <div class="form-section form-half-section quote">
    <span class="quote-label">Width</span>
    <span class="input-wrap currency"><input id="splash-width" type="number" value="0"></span></div>
        <div class="form-section form-half-section quote">
        <span class="quote-label">Length </span>
        <span class="input-wrap currency"><input id="splash-length" type="number" value="0"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="additional-splashback"></div>

        <a class="clonebutton" href="" >Add More</a>
        <div class="form-section quote">
        <input id="splash-result" value="0" readonly>
</div>
 </div>
<div class="worktop-calc">
        <span class="quote-label">Integrity Sink</span>
        <div class="input-wrap currency extraproduct" data-price="600.00">
        <input type="number" class="extraQuantity" value="0"  min="0" max="20" />
        <span class="productTotal"></span>
        </div>

        <span class="quote-label">Pop Up Socket Cut Out</span>
        <div class="input-wrap currency extraproduct" data-price="50.00">
        <input type="number" class="extraQuantity" value="0"  min="0" max="20" />
        <span class="productTotal"></span>
        </div>

        /** 1ST Total I'm Trying to Add **/
        <div id="total" readonly="readonly">Total: £<span id="sum" class="sumthree">0.00</span> </div> 
</div>
<div class="fitting-calc">
        <div class="form-section quote">
            <span class="quote-label">Templating</span>
            <span class="input-wrap checkbox-wrap"><input type="checkbox" value="120.00"></span>
            <br>
                        <span class="quote-label">Delivery</span>
            <span class="input-wrap checkbox-wrap"><input type="checkbox" value="250.00"></span>
        </div>

/** 2nd Total I'm trying to add **/     
<input id="fittingprice" class="sumthree" type="text" readonly="readonly"/>

</div>

   /** 3rd Total I'm trying to add, grabs product price and measurements to calculate the sum **/
<span class="input-wrap total-cost">£<input id="total-cost" class="sumthree" readonly type="number" min="0" step="0.01" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="100"></span>

/** The Total of the 3 other Totals I'm trying to solve **/
<span class="input-wrap">£<input id="quotefinal" readonly type="number" min="0" step="0.01" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="100"></span>
```

---

```
(function($){
    $('.worktop-calc input').change(function() {
        var area   = $('#works-width').val() * $('#works-length').val()
        $('#works-result').val(area)
    })
    $('.splashback-calc input').change(function() {
        var area   = $('#splash-width').val() * $('#splash-length').val()
        $('#splash-result').val(area)
    })
    $('.clonebutton').first().click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $( ".splashback-row" ).clone().appendTo( ".splashback-row" );
    });


$( '.variations_form' ).each( function() {
    jQuery(this).on( 'found_variation', function( event, variation ) {
        console.log(variation);//all details here
        var price = variation.display_price;//selectedprice
        console.log(price);
        var totalcost = (price) * $('#works-result').val() 
        $('#total-cost').val(totalcost)
    });

var updateTotal = function() {

var sumtotal;
   var sum = 0;
//Add each product price to total
$(".extraproduct").each(function() {
    var extra_price = $(this).data('price');
    var quantity = $('.extraQuantity', this).val();

    //Total for one product
    var subtotal = extra_price*quantity;     
     //Round to 2 decimal places.
    subtotal = subtotal.toFixed(2);      
    //Display subtotal in HTML element
    $('.productTotal', this).html(subtotal);
});
// total
   $('.productTotal').each(function() {
    sum += Number($(this).html());
}); 
$('#sum').html(sum.toFixed(2));
};
 //Update total when quantity changes
$(".extraQuantity").bind("keyup change", function() {
updateTotal();
});
//Update totals when page first loads
updateTotal();
// set this from local
$('span.productTotal').each(function() {
    $(this).before("£")
}); 
// unit price
$('.extraproduct span').each(function() {
   var $price = $(this).parents("div").data('price');
  $(this).before($price);
}); 

$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
var totalprice = 0;
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
    totalprice= totalprice + parseInt($(this).val());
});
$('#fittingprice').val(totalprice);
});


// THE BIT THAT SHOULD OUTPUT THE SUM OF THE 3 TOTALS
$("span, .sumthree").change(function(){
  var finalquote = 0;
    $(".sumthree").each(function() {
       finalquote = finalquote + parseInt($(this).html());
    });
    $('#quotefinal').val(finalquote);
    console.log(finalquote);
  });

});
})(jQuery)
```

I've cut down the HTML so it's a bit more understandable. I've included a JSFiddle to see the full code if needed. https://jsfiddle.net/DigitalAdam/c2jpawy4/2/

If you think I need to cut the JS down more, please let me know and I'll see what I can do. I'm new to doing calculators in Jquery and due to the nature of the calculator the above code all seemed relevant to me.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember JQuery's `val()` function returns a string. Try passing your values to `parseInt()` to get integers so you can do calculations.

`parseInt($('#works-width').val())` etc...

Update: `$('.variations_form').each` block wraps most of your code. close it before you declare `updateTotal` to fix most functionality. Still working on the final though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this then as I hadn't considered parseInt for the earlier calculations. If I use it on each value apart from the final calculation it returns 'Val is not defined' instead of 'NaN'. If I pass it in the final calculation as well it returns 'NaN' again unfortunately.